# Does a user lose his privileges if he sets a bounty which takes him below the required reputation score for the privilege?

Tags: support

let's say a user has 300 reputation points (allows you to create new tags) and then he starts a bounty which costs him 50 points, Will he lose the ability to create the new tags or once certain reputation is achieved the privileges are saved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you will lose privileges.

See https://serverfault.com/help/bounty

> If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any
>   privileges, you will lose access to those privileges.